# Can This jQuery Dropdown Script be Simplified?

Tags: jquery, compression, simplify

I have two scripts, that I have created. One which is for the desktop multi-level dropdown navigation, and the second which is for when it goes responsive. Is there a way to simplify/compress this script, which I am not seeing?

Here is my simplified version.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul.primary li').click(function () {
    var a = this;
    if ($('ul', this).is(':visible')) {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(function () {
            $(a).removeClass('active')
        })
    } else {
        $('ul.drop').slideUp();
        $('ul.primary li').removeClass('active');
        $('ul', this).slideDown();
        $(a).addClass('active')
    }
});
$('body').click(function (a) {
    if (!$(a.target).is('a')) {
        $('ul.drop').slideUp();
        $('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
    }
});
$(function () {
    $('.mobile-nav').click(function (e) {
        $('.primary').slideToggle(150, "swing");
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('ul.drop').slideUp();
        $('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
    });
})
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="mobile-nav">Navigation</div>
        <ul class="primary">
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="has-drop">Link w/ Children <span></span></a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="has-drop" href="#link">Link w/ Children <span></span></a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I am having now, is that the window.Resize function isn't firing all the time. I am seeking to close all open ul.drop's when the window is resized.

Also, when resizing my browser back to desktop width, my ul.drops seem to cut-off and will not slideDown past the containing element until i refresh.

Comment: can you provide the HTML markup that goes along with this? Many jQUery patterns are heavily dependent on the markup. Simplifying it may not just be function of cleaner / fewer lines of JS.

Comment: I have provided it in an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ is a good place to compress it yourself.
Pretty self explanatory how to use :)

Comment: Thanks, i've never used that before!